# Config schema type for array-or-string?

Tags: configuration

I have just written a "complicated" `@Filter` plugin which does this:

```
public function process($text, $langcode) {
  return new FilterProcessResult(str_replace($this->settings['from'], $this->settings['to'], $text));
}
```

Now, both `from` and `to` can either be an array or a string (except the `from` string and `to` array case makes no sense.) For now I just dropped

```
filter_settings.str_replace:
  type: filter
  label: 'Filter URL'
  mapping:
    from:
      type: ignore
      label: from
    to:
      type: ignore
      label: to
```

Is there a more specific type? Is it possible for me to add a type?

Comment: This page can help you more: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-schemametadata, and in particular, this cheat sheet: https://www.drupal.org/files/ConfigSchemaCheatSheet1.5.pdf. I'm thinking you'll probably want the section on 'configuring dynamic configuration with [%parent]' from the cheatsheet.

Comment: Would not *%parent.type* refer to `type: filter`, in this case?